# Is it possible to create a branch that is a copy of master branch files for testing?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Is it possible to create a testing branch, that is essentially a clone of the master branch, but for in-depth testing and debugging while users are using the live site? Then, replace the old file with the updated one from the clone on the master branch when an update is ready to go live? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Umm fork a branch and then do testing and then merge it? I hope i got your question right

Comment: For example, my GitHub repository is my live site folder locally ... can I make a test branch with another folder locally (for testing), then push tested files to the master branch (live site) when ready?

Comment: I am assuming you are working on master branch? Just create a fork of your master branch with name of say slave, now pull code from slave to your local machine and make changes in there and then push it to the same slave branch, when update is ready merge it with master.

Comment: I think my master branch is already on my local machine? For example when I make a change in my code, it shows up on my live site, before it's committed to the master branch and synced ... or do only I see local changes while the live site externally updates when I commit a change to the master branch?

Comment: Create a fork of branch and checkout that branch on your local machine.. I would suggest you to go through git basics once

Comment: `my GitHub repository is my live site folder locally` Are you hosting this site to users off of your development machine, and doing development directly on those same files? If so, that might be your problem right there.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create a testing branch, that is essentially a clone of the master branch, but for in-depth testing and debugging while users are using the live site

very simple:

```
git checkout master

git checkout -b <new branch>
```

---

Using git version > 2.5 you can always use `git worktree add <second path>` and you will have a copy working folder with the same code but in different folders.

Comment: I use this command all the time. you `git checkout -b master (or origin/master)`, work whatever magic you need on the new branch, and either delete the branch if you don't need it, or `git push/review` your changes into master.

Comment: I was playing around in GitShell with `git worktree add <second path>` and `git checkout master` and g`it checkout -b <new branch>` commands. Before, my master branch was synced with local folder W:\branch1. Now it's synced with local folder W:\branch2. I think I accidentally switched something. How do I switch it back?

Answer (score 1):

checkout your project in another folder and make a branch. Configure your server to serve both folder. One for the "production", one for your test.

the good way is not to copy files. But to do a "git clone"  in the project-test folder.
When done, do a "git branch -b myNewTestBranch" to create your new branch.
Configure your server to also use this folder.
Then do your tests.
When you think it's OK
commit and push.
Then go back on your master and merge it with your test branch.
IMO this is the right way. But if you work alone you can do what you've discribe but it's the "dirty way"

Comment: This sounds like great logic ... I'm learning ... how is this acheived? Copy files from project folder to another folder (like "project-test"), then manually copy and paste updated code to project folder (master branch) when ready?

Comment: the good way is not to copy files. But to do a "git clone"  in the project-test folder.
When done, do a "git branch -b myNewTestBranch" to create your new branch.
Configure your server to also use this folder.
Then do your tests.
When you think it's OK
commit and push.
Then go back on your master and merge it with your test branch.